# How to mock a dependency in Jasmine/Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a method, that I want to unit test, but in the method there is a dependency to a storageService. I don't understand, how I can mock the dependency the right way so the mock is called instead and returns a certain value. Please help me.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ProductDataService } from './product-data.service';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';

describe('ProductDataService', () => {
  let service: ProductDataService;
  let storageServiceSpy;
  
  let mockFileId, getMock;
  
  getMock = (key: string): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (key == "PRODUCT_DATA_INFO_LOCAL") {
        return resolve();
      } else {
        return reject();
      }
    })
  }

  beforeEach(() => {    
    mockFileId = "test";
    
    storageServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('StorageService', ['get', 'set']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: StorageService, useValue: storageServiceSpy }
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ProductDataService);
  });

  it('should call getFileInfo and resolve', (done) => {
    let spy = spyOn(storageServiceSpy, 'get').and.callFake(getMock("PRODUCT_DATA_INFO_LOCAL"));
    service['getFileInfo'](mockFileId).then((data) => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    })

  })
});
```

Jasmine gives me the following error:

> Error:  : get has already been spied upon

Comment: It _has_ already been spied on; you don't need `spyOn` when you created the test double with `createSpyObj`. Look at the example in e.g. https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#testing-with-a-spy.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but it doesn't work if I delete the StorageServiceSpy and try to spyOn StorageService directly in the test case. Then I have a problem with "never"-datatypes, which I don't have using the spy.

Comment: You could give a [mre] of that problem, or just use the spied methods you're already creating.

Comment: sorry, I deleted some more stuff to make it more simple

Comment: I mean giving a [mre] of the problem you had with trying to spyOn the real implementation. This is still showing the same problem, which is exactly what the error message tells you: you can't (and don't need to) spy on something that's already a spy (because it's already a spy).

Answer (score 0):

I mangaged to do it by myself. Here is the code:

```
describe('ProductDataService', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductDataService>;
  let component: ProductDataService;
  let service: ProductDataService;
  
  let mockFileId;

  const mockStorageService = {    
    get: () => {return Promise.resolve();}
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {    
    mockFileId = "test";    

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: StorageService, useValue: mockStorageService }
      ]
    })
    service = TestBed.inject(ProductDataService);
  }));

  it('should call getFileInfo and resolve', async (done) => {    
    let spy = spyOn<any>(mockStorageService, 'get').and.resolveTo(['foo', 'bar']);

    service['getFileInfo'](mockFileId).then((data) => {
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    })
  })
  
});
```

I think the key was mocking the service as a const on the one hand and on the other hand creating the spy later in the test case. I also declared the test-case as async, because of these timeout errors.
Maybe someone knows more about it?